# class variable initialization in cpp

Tags: android, c++

I have a class like this,

```
class CLv
{
public:
    BOOL operator == (const CLv& lv) const
    {
        return _value == lv._value && _fStart == lv._fStart;
    }
    BOOL operator != (const CLv& lv) const
    {
        return _value != lv._value || _fStart != lv._fStart;
    }
    BYTE    _value;             
    BYTE    _fStart :1;         
};
```

Then, what does the below code segment mean?

```
CLv        lvEnd = {0,0};
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the canonical form of `operator!=` is just `return !operator==(lv);`. This way you just have one operator (`operator==`) to maintain from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the variable `lvEnd` of type `CLv` is initialized with values of `0` and `0` for its members `_value` and `_fStart`.

Your class is an aggregate:

#### 8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]

> 1) An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers
>   for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

And can be list-initialized:

#### 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]

> 1) List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list. Such an initializer is
>   called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the list are called the elements of the
>   initializer list. [...]

Comment: Thank you Luchian Grigore and simonc.